# Data from response is symbols unable to set to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, httpresponse

I want to check if a response was successful from an Api and then put it in the iframe.

If I call it twice like this... it works.

```
function getPDF(fileDirectorGuid) {
if ($('#viewDownloadWindow').is(":visible")) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#fdApiURL').val() + 'getDocAsPDF' + FIRST_ARGS + '&guid=' + fileDirectorGuid + '&fallbackToNative=true',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == null) {
                alert("failed");
            }
            else {
                $('#pdfFrame').attr('src', $('#fdApiURL').val() + 'getDocAsPDF' + FIRST_ARGS + '&guid=' + fileDirectorGuid + '&fallbackToNative=true');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

however I don't want to call this twice and this doesn't work out like I thought

```
function getPDF(fileDirectorGuid) {
if ($('#viewDownloadWindow').is(":visible")) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#fdApiURL').val() + 'getDocAsPDF' + FIRST_ARGS + '&guid=' + fileDirectorGuid + '&fallbackToNative=true',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == null) {
                alert("failed");
            }
            else {
                $('#pdfFrame').attr('src', data);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

When viewing this in the debugger data looks like this

```
"%PDF-1.6
1 0 obj
<<
/Length 2 0 R
/Filter  /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x��[�%Iv�wO�����H�|��8&`%ِږ8�.���D�J�h  ��^of�Z�;wsj�g�<�4��O�X�Nq���c��������l����������7��?����>���S������4��>�y||��z�<J����Gݏ�c�?C����6�����?
```

so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The src attribute of an iframe is a url, you're setting the actual pdf data. You can use a blob url to achieve your goal

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#fdApiURL').val() + 'getDocAsPDF' + FIRST_ARGS + '&guid=' + fileDirectorGuid + '&fallbackToNative=true',
    type: 'GET',
    xhr:function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType= 'blob'
        return xhr;
    },        
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == null) {
            alert("failed");
        }
        else {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            $('#pdfFrame').attr('src', url);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew I was missing something rather simple, this worked.